# Apple Pay - PKPassLibrary isSecureElementPassActivationAvailable

Tags: ios, swift, applepay, passkit

I am implementing Apple Pay as a card issuer.
I am having troubles using new function in `PKPassLibrary`(tested on real devices)

```swift
@available(iOS 13.4, *)
open var isSecureElementPassActivationAvailable: Bool { get }
```

It seems to always return false. For older version I use `isPaymentPassActivationAvailable()` which is working fine, but the problem is, that it is deprecated for newer versions.

Does anyone have a solution, besides opting to use the deprecated call?

**EDIT**

Another option is to use `PKAddPaymentPassViewController.canAddPaymentPass()` which seems to be working fine

Answer (score 0):

You could use `isSecureElementPassActivationAvailable`.